# MVVMCROSS ShowViewModel-Navigation Inherited Class

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there a way to do ShoViewModel-Navigation with own inherited classes with mvvmcross? For example:

```
public class myviewcontroller:MvxViewController
```

Inherited ViewController:

```
public class myInheritedViewController:myviewcontroller
```

Problem is similiar to: [MVVMCROSS Ios Binding ShowViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055442/mvvmcross-ios-binding-showviewmodel) but base.viewdidload() won't solve the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt any ViewController base class to allow binding by inheriting from it to provide the MvvmCross data-binding extensions.

For example, see how UIViewController itself is adapted in 2 layers of inheritance:

- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch/Views/MvxEventSourceViewController.cs
- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxViewController.cs

There's more on this in a few other questions here on StackOverflow - e.g. see [Integrating third party controller with MVVMCross on MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153981/integrating-third-party-controller-with-mvvmcross-on-monotouch/18158433#18158433)